# How many relations on a set with 6 elements?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

I know there is a lot of information on this internet for this, I've been going through it the past 30 minutes. I'm getting confused to if the answer is actually 203 relations, because when I try to calculate only reflexive, symmetry, and both reflexive & symmetry I get much higher numbers then 203.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Hint: What is a relation in terms of set theory? That's how to get started. You don't care about reflexivity or any other properties. Just the number of relations. This problem is actually easy once you understand what they're asking.

Comment: I believe the answer is 203 relations according to bell numbers but I have no idea why... @user4894

Comment: What is the definition of a relation? Why do you think the Bell numbers are relevant? Can you write out more of your thought process? I'm asking because you're reading something in to the problem that's not there. The question is about relations, not a particular type of relation.

Comment: R is a subset of A X A. That is what I believe is a relation. I figured bell number because it counts the paritions in a set. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number

Comment: also an answer similar to this question mentioned bell numbers

Comment: Right, but a partition is a particular type of relation. You already have the right def, how many subsets of A X A are there? There are a lot more than 203, right?

Comment: So how would you go about calculating so many?

Comment: I'll post an answer.

Comment: I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A relation is any subset of $A \times A$. Given any set $X$, the number of subsets is $2^{\lvert X \rvert}$.

So the number of relations on a 6-element set is $2^{36}$. Big number! For example one relation could be $\{(1,2)\}$. In other words 1R2 and that's the entire relation. You can see that there are a lot of possible relations.

An *equivalence* relation is the same as a partition, so the Bell numbers tell you how many equivalence relations there are on a given set. But you are asked to find how many relations there are of any type. So the partitions aren't relevant here.

Comment: This is perfect! I totally get it now! Thank you for sticking around to help!

Comment: You're very welcome.